# How to share .pdf,.doc file into my application

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-manifest, android-sharing

I would like to share pdf,doc file from some application(example google drive,dropbox) to my android application.

**What I tried**

I can share a image into my application using these code snippet,I can get that image path using below code in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />



                 <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> 


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


            </intent-filter>
```

**In my Activity**

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = myintent.getExtras();
            String action = myintent.getAction();

            // if this is from the share menu
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {   if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            // Get resource path
            Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            String filename = parseUriToFilename(uri);

            if (filename != null) {


                doing some process here//

            }
            }
            }

public String parseUriToFilename(Uri uri) {
            String selectedImagePath = null;
            String filemanagerPath = uri.getPath();

            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
            // Here you will get a null pointer if cursor is null
            // This can be if you used OI file manager for picking the media
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
            return selectedImagePath;
            }
            else if (filemanagerPath != null) {
            return filemanagerPath;
            }
        return null;
            }
```

**what I actually need**

using above code I can get shared image path so that I can perform my task.I would like to share .pdf,.doc file into my app for that purpose I need exact location of the file.so how can I get pdf,doc file path if I shared these files into my Application.

Answer (score 0):

> using above code I can get shared image path so that I can perform my task

No, you can get the path to *some* images, those that happen to be indexed by the `MediaStore`. Not all images are indexed by the `MediaStore`. Not all images are stored in files at paths that your app can access.

More generally, [not every `content://` `Uri` that you will find will be represented by a file that you can access](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Instead, you will need to consume the content using the appropriate `ContentResolver` methods, like `openInputStream()`.

> I would like to share .pdf,.doc file into my app for that purpose I need exact location of the file

For those files that happen to also be indexed by `MediaStore`, you are welcome to attempt to use the same solution as you did for images indexed by `MediaStore`.

Comment: how can I get the pdf file path.? may you provide any example code for getting a file path.